# Need index path.row for textfield

Tags: uitableview, xcode5, xib

I am using xib file with label on left side and textfield on right side.
I am using this xib in UI Tableview. I need row value whenever i click on textfield (Right side).

I am able to get row value on left side(Label side) but not on the textfield.

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with tagging Textfield?
i.e. Give a **tag** to **textfield** and on **didSelect** get that tag by

```
textfield.tag
```

and use it wherever you want.

Comment: How you tried this can u please provide a little piece of code ?

Comment: I already reverted that changes, friend in did select whenever i click on textfield it doesn't give me index path.row value and if i click on label part, i am able to get index path value.

And moreover i need to use same textfield two times and need different restriction , so tagging didn't work.